# $match on $project-computed-field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an aggregation query where `$project` extracts the year from a timestamp like so:

```
{
        $project: {
                year : {$year : { $add: [new Date(0), {$multiply: ["$timestampField", 1000 ]}]}},   
                ...
```

My wish is to use a `$gte` operator in such a way to filter the output result, but the result remains inchanged when I apply `$gte` on the year field like this:

```
{
            $project: {
                year : {$gte: [{$year : { $add: [new Date(0), {$multiply: ["$timestampField", 1000 ]}]}}, 2018]},  
                ...
```

I've naturally tried to use `$gte` on `$match`, but the output result is [] (void) since - I believe - the field year is computed in the query and `$match` can only operate on preexisting fields. In short, something like this doesn't work:

```
{
            $project: {
                year : {$year : { $add: [new Date(0), {$multiply: ["$timestampField", 1000 ]}]}},  
                ...

 {
            $match: {
                "year": {$gte: 2018},
                ...
```

I am not considering adding the computed field to the collection schema to leverage `$match`, other than that, i don't seem to find any documentation on how to satisfy my use case.

Is it doable? If so, what am I missing?

**EDIT :**
A sample-document from the collection:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a27b4d4c14826880321c8e4"
    },
    "ope": "ptp",
    "shopId": "121",
    "ptst": 6,
    "timestampField": 1512554442
}
```

Comment: That should work. Can you add a sample document to your question that you expect to be included in the results?

Comment: Edited, yeah done some more research and it apprears `$match` on computed-fields should work just fine.

Comment: That document's `year` evaluates to 2017, so that's why it's not matched.

Comment: Well that was just an example, I have document's which translate to a `year`-value of 2018.

Comment: You do realize a computation needs to scan the "whole collection" right? Because the logical thing is to simply supply the timestamp value to compare with a regular query operator. ie `var start = new Date("2018-01-01").valueOf() / 1000; db.collection.find({ "timestampField": { "$gte": start } });` Get's you the same results only much faster. Especially if you index the timestamp value. You might have done a calculation with a SQL database, but it's as bad an idea then as it is now. Calculate "outside"  the query.

Comment: @NeilLunn: I've actually tried that workaround: there's still the option of doing the comparison with the timestamp instead of using the many date's fields, still, I was just curious as to why this query doesn't work. Thanks for pointing it out anyways, still might be usefull to someone in a similar situation.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work?" Everything you show here ( whilst simply not a good idea ) does actually work. Do you actually mean because you have split up your timestamp with `$year`, `$month`, etc that your conditions then don't actually work? Or do you mean "really dog slow horrible does not work for me" because of the exact condition I just described?

Comment: Because of the split, I am still wondering why it is not working, it most probably is something stupid but I can't seem to figure it out. And it doesn't work as in it return undefined or [] as explained in the post question.